# CKEditor scayt Plugin module

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

I'm trying to build a scayt module to be able to use the CKEditor scayt Plugin. I tried to use this module but it did not work for me. https://github.com/nikhildodeja/scayt  I created my own but I get a WSOD when I veiw a node creat page. The module is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
        <?php

    /**
    * @file
    * Definition of \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\Scayt.
    */

    namespace Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

    use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;
    use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;


    /**
    * Defines the "Scayt" plugin.
    *
    * @CKEditorPlugin(
    *   id = "scayt",
    *   label = @Translation("Scayt CKEditor")
    * )
    */

    class Scayt extends CKEditorPluginBase{

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getDependencies().
    */
    function getDependencies(Editor $editor) {
    return array('panelbutton','floatpanel','menu','menubutton','dialogui','button');
    }

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getLibraries().
    */
    function getLibraries(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
    }

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::isInternal().
    */
    function isInternal() {
    return FALSE;
    }

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile().
    */
    function getFile() {
        return 'libraries/scayt/plugin.js';
    }

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface::getButtons().
    */
    function getButtons() {
    return array(
      'Scayt' => array(
        'label' => t('Spell Check'),
        'image' => 'libraries/scayt/icons/scayt.png',
      ),
    );
    }

    /**
    * Implements \Drupal\scayt\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getConfig().
    */
    public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return array();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Going to assume you don't have the Panel Button module + plugin installed. Beyond that you will need to provide error logs.

Comment: I do have Panel button installed and a few other plugins. watchdog shows no errors. I was able to get the button into the ckeditor toolbar. But after messing with my module I could not load the node create page

Comment: If its a WSOD there must be an error log somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error it's difficult to know, but you do at least need to extend `CKEditorPluginBase` rather than `PluginBase`:

```
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;

class Scayt extends CKEditorPluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface, CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface {
```

Otherwise the [required interface methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21src%21CKEditorPluginInterface.php/interface/CKEditorPluginInterface/8.2.x) won't be satisfied.

Comment: You are right I should use both of these: use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;

Comment: I also left out its dependencies: panelbutton','floatpanel','menu','menubutton','dialogui','button

Comment: I also looked at a Drupal 7 site that has Scayt working and found there are 2 scayt buttons that need to be added. One is called Spell check and the other "Spell Check as You Type" button to your toolbar

Comment: I got Scayt work. I updated my first post with the code. I am trying now to enable scayt when the node opens? Also in Drupal 8 how can I add ckeditor config like this: config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

Comment: You need to do a combination of things. Check the CKEditor CodeSnippet module for tips on what to do in all of those cases.